# Строковой литерал на позиции инициализатора массива char'ов

Tags: c++, char, const

В книге Бьёрна Страуструпа "Язык программирования С++. Специальное издание. 2011г. (стр.176)" увидел достаточно лаконичный способ инициализации **массива char'ов** *константным строковым литералом*:

> Например, копирование строк с терминальным нулем можно выполнить
> следующим образом:
>
> ```
> void cpy (char* p, const char* q)
> {
> while (*p++=*q++);
> }
> ```

Решил проверить корректность работы в Visual Studio 2020

Накидал простенький код:

```
const int size = 14;
const char* str1 = "Hello, World!";
char* str2 = new char[size];

while(*str2++ = *str1++);
```

На выходе получил мусор. Почему?

Если массив char'ов создаём в стеке, а не в куче

> char str2[size];

- в строке с условием цикла выдаёт ошибку: ***"выражение должно иметь константное значение c++ массив"***

Проверку на корректность вывода массива сhar'ов осуществлял следующим образом:

```
while (*str2)
  std::cout << *str2++;
```

Comment: Вы же меняете при копировании указатель `str2`, а другого указателя на `new char[size]` у вас нет. Как вы проверяли, что после копирования находится по **начальному значению** `str2`? Покажите код целиком. Как вы проверяли, что в выделенном новом массиве мусор?

Comment: @CrazyElf, благодарю! Классическая ошибка на невнимательность при работе! В таких случаях вопрос корректнее удалить?

Comment: Да я не знаю, нужно ли такие вопросы удалять. Пусть знатоки С++ придут с скажут есть от таких вопросов польза или нет. А может это дубликат, тогда закроют как дубликат. )

Comment: @Bizzarro Я думаю вопрос и решение полезно. В С++ есть string а в Си его нет :) Так что для Си это полезно.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка заключалась в банальной невнимательности!
После копирования содержимого строкового литерала, `str2` указывал на область памяти за границами массива, поэтому на выходе получался мусор.
Следовательно, как вариант, при определении массива `str2`, можно было создать еще один указатель на начало массива `str2` и уже его использовать для просмотра содержимого массива:

```
 char* str2 = new char[size];
 char* str3 = str2;

 while (*str3)
   std::cout << *str3++;
```

Comment: @CrazyElf, точно! Благодарю! Сейчас подправлю.